# Example of Complex Pythagorean Triples

Tags: reference-request, complex-numbers, soft-question, examples-counterexamples, pythagorean-triples

I am looking for example of a Pythagorean Triple with Gaussian Integers.

I followed the links and looked at followings :

Relation to Gaussian integers in
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple

Links and Google searches mentioned in:
[Generating all the Pythagorean triples by factorizing using complex numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/886223/generating-all-the-pythagorean-triples-by-factorizing-using-complex-numbers)

And

[References for generating Pythagorean triple using complex number](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2707556/references-for-generating-pythagorean-triple-using-complex-number)

Just looking for an example of a Pythagorean Triple as Gaussian integers, must be missing something obvious in all the above and their mentioned links to not come up with Just one example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Examples :**
$$(-4+1i)^2+(4+8i)^2=(4+7i)^2$$
$$(-4-1i)^2+(4-8i)^2=(4-7i)^2$$

**Multiples :**
$$(-8+2i)^2+(8+16i)^2=(8+14i)^2$$
$$(-12-3i)^2+(12-24i)^2=(12-21i)^2$$

By the way , we can see that all "Ordinary" Pythagorean triples are also "Complex" Pythagorean triples : (1) by setting Imaginary Part to $0$ or (2) by multiplying by $i$ or (3) by multiplying by arbitrary gaussian integer $z$ :
$$(3+0i)^2+(4+0i)^2=(5+0i)^2$$
$$(0+3i)^2+(0+4i)^2=(0+5i)^2$$
$$(3z)^2+(4z)^2=(5z)^2$$

### ADDENDUM :

Some more Examples with Positive Integers :
$$( 1 + 5 i)^2+( 9 + 3 i)^2=( 8 + 4 i)^2$$
$$( 2 + 3 i)^2+( 6 + 2 i)^2=( 6 + 3 i)^2$$
$$( 2 + 9 i)^2+( 7 + 6 i)^2=( 6 + 10 i)^2$$
$$( 2 + 9 i)^2+( 9 + 2 i)^2=( 6 + 6 i)^2$$
$$( 3 + 6 i)^2+( 6 + 3 i)^2=( 6 + 6 i)^2$$
$$( 4 + 1 i)^2+( 7 + 4 i)^2=( 8 + 4 i)^2$$
$$( 5 + 5 i)^2+( 7 + 1 i)^2=( 8 + 4 i)^2$$
$$( 6 + 2 i)^2+( 2 + 3 i)^2=( 6 + 3 i)^2$$
$$( 6 + 3 i)^2+( 3 + 6 i)^2=( 6 + 6 i)^2$$
$$( 6 + 3 i)^2+( 8 + 4 i)^2=( 10 + 5 i)^2$$
$$( 7 + 1 i)^2+( 5 + 5 i)^2=( 8 + 4 i)^2$$
$$( 7 + 4 i)^2+( 4 + 1 i)^2=( 8 + 4 i)^2$$
$$( 7 + 6 i)^2+( 2 + 9 i)^2=( 6 + 10 i)^2$$
$$( 8 + 4 i)^2+( 6 + 3 i)^2=( 10 + 5 i)^2$$
$$( 8 + 9 i)^2+( 9 + 8 i)^2=( 12 + 12 i)^2$$
$$( 9 + 2 i)^2+( 2 + 9 i)^2=( 6 + 6 i)^2$$
$$( 9 + 3 i)^2+( 1 + 5 i)^2=( 8 + 4 i)^2$$
$$( 9 + 8 i)^2+( 8 + 9 i)^2=( 12 + 12 i)^2$$

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried working through an algebraic derivation of the primitive Pythagorean triple parametric formula in $\mathbf Z$ to get an analogue in $\mathbf Z[i]$?  Because $-1$ is a square, the terms in $\alpha^2 + \beta^2 = \gamma^2$ are essentially symmetric in $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\gamma$, so we can assume without loss of generality that $\beta$ is divisible by $1+i$ while $\alpha$ and $\gamma$ are not. Then it turns out that
$$
\alpha = u(z^2 - w^2), \ \beta = \pm 2uzw, \ \gamma = u(z^2+w^2)
$$
where $u$ is a unit in the Gaussian integers, $z$ and $w$ are relatively prime in the Gaussian integers, and $z \not\equiv w \bmod 1+i$.

Comment: Have I tried that? Dude I didn't even knew that method even exists, but will definitely try as much as I csn. i couldn't even come up with one example let alone the whole algorithm!

Comment: Observation : Technically there is nothing wrong here , though this is the type of answer which @jimjim came across already & could not get a Single Example ! Ironically this answer too gives no Examples !

Comment: @Prem I did not look at any links in the post. The OP can just plug in values to get an example: taking $u = 1$, $z = 1+i$, and $w = 1$, we get $\alpha = 2i - 1 = -1+2i$, $\beta = 2+2i$ (I use the plus sign there), and $\gamma = 2i+1 = 1 + 2i$.  Then we have $(-1+2i)^2 + (2+2i)^2 = (1+2i)^2$.

Comment: How do you sub some values in that to get some examples? I am stumped, no idea how to use that to make some concrete cases

Comment: @jimjim do you know how to plug in numbers for variables n an algebraic formula? If $a = m^2 - n^2$ and I set $m=4$ and $n=3$, do you agree that $a=16-9 = 7$?

Comment: @KCd, there is no a,m,n in the answer. Sorry , I am used to clearly described formulas like in programming , this is way to abstract and generic to make sense as a procedure.

Comment: Aaah, just saw your comment, I try what is in your comment instead. Thank you

Comment: No worries , I did say "Technically there is nothing wrong here" & it was just my Observation that many answers give the useful outlines without giving Concrete Examples which OP was looking for !